# How to change the textarea in custom fields?

Tags: wordpress

I want to use custom fields for adding many links in a post and i want to change the textarea and replace it with some text input and checkbox and concat the values with ";"

[image]

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave that alone, you need to add your own [Custom Meta Boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and deal with Custom Fields inside it.

There are examples in the Codex and you can [check this search results](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2badd_meta_box%20%2bsave_post%20is:a) for more. Or use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) that makes everything easier and faster.